# Why my ldap login does not work?

Tags: java, spring, maven, ldap

I need to be able to login with uidnumber and uid, but i keep getting errors like:

```
    testCreateEmployee(com.companyName.personnel.services.EmployeeServiceImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.021 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.companyName.personnel.services.EmployeeServiceImplTest.tearDown(EmployeeServiceImplTest.java:60)

testCreateEmployeeFailsWhenNoMandatorycomelds(com.companyName.personnel.services.EmployeeServiceImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.02 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException: Unable to add entry 'uidnumber=1,uid=johnsmith,ou=people,o=companyName,dc=companyName,dc=com' because its parent entry 'uid=johnsmith,ou=people,o=companyName,dc=companyName,dc=com' smiths not exist in the server.
    at com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryRequestHandler.addEntry(InMemoryRequestHandler.java:4027)
    at com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryRequestHandler.importFromLDIF(InMemoryRequestHandler.java:3848)
    at com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryDirectoryServer.importFromLDIF(InMemoryDirectoryServer.java:1216)
    at com.companyName.personnel.utils.companyNameInMemoryDirectoryServer.init(companyNameInMemoryDirectoryServer.java:37)
    at com.companyName.personnel.services.EmployeeServiceImplTest.setUp(EmployeeServiceImplTest.java:43)
```

my LDAP code that does not work:

```
    dn: uidnumber=1,uid=johnsmith,ou=people,o=companyName,dc=companyName,dc=com
activestatus: TRUE
cn: John smith
gidnumber: 5002
givenname: John
homedirectory: /home/johnsmith
loginshell: /bin/bash
mail: john.smith@companyName.com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: companyNamePerson
objectclass: pwmUser
objectclass: top
objectclass: posixAccount
sn: smith
telephonenumber: +123123123
title: Software Developer
uid: johnsmith
uidnumber: 1
```

Program is made with java + spring/maven. Any help is appericated!

Comment: 1) You have not shown us the Java code; 2) The error says you are attempting to add an entry, NOT login.

Comment: @Jim Garrison code works with uid, and java code is a mess that is in 6 different classes :/ edit: i think code should work but i cant add that entry to ldap.... and not  sure why

Comment: We cannot help you then.  There is nothing for us to look at and we cannot read your mind.  Would you expect an auto mechanic to fix your car over the phone, without seeing it?

Comment: @Jim Garrison added more detailed error code, maybe it will help point at right direction?

Comment: Did you read the error message? `Unable to add entry 'uid=johnsmith,...,dc=com,gidnumber: 5002' because an error occurred while attempting to parse the DN:  The provided string could not be decoded as a DN because no equal sign was found after the RDN attribute 'gidnumber:'.`Looks like you are invoking an API (which one) with that block of data as an argument, and it does not like the format of the data.  Beyond that we cannot help.